# Android`s native size

Tags: android, memory-management, native

I saw great article below,

[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813)

but, I have a question in that article,

```
** MEMINFO in pid 890 [system] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:    10940     7047      N/A    17987
       allocated:     8943     5516      N/A    14459
            free:      336     1531      N/A     1867
           (Pss):     4585     9282    11916    25783
  (shared dirty):     2184     3596      916     6696
    (priv dirty):     4504     5956     7456    17916
```

Heap size make sense, however native size is ridiculous.
Why not NativeFree = NativeSize - NativeAllocated ?
I uploaded question like this, but answer doesn`t help me. I ask again.